# Student Info Recorder with Alphabetical and Ascending ID Displayer and Subject Filter using Multi-Dimensional Array

Tags: arrays, user-interface, exception, try-catch, user-interaction

This is the part of my codes which I want to use try-catch exception,Now how to use try and catch exception in this codes? Example if there is no enrolled students in case no.3(prog2) and case no.4(CSO), it displays NO ENROLLED students...

```
   switch(menu){
       case 1:
           System.out.println("******[1]Output******");
           sortNameSub(file1);
           for(int str=0;str<5;str++)
               System.out.println(file1[str]);
           System.out.print("Press [r] to return to main manu....");
           String r=copy.next();
           if("r".equals(r))
               break;
       case 2:
           System.out.println("*****[2]Output******");
           for(int x=0;x<5;x++){
               sortId(file2);
               for(int y=0;y<5;y++){
               if(Integer.parseInt(file[y][1])==file2[x])
                  System.out.println(file2[x]+";"+file[y][0]);
               }                
           }

           System.out.print("Press [r] to return to main manu....");
           r=copy.next();
           if("r".equals(r))
           break;
       case 3:
           System.out.println("******[3]Output*****");

           for(int x=0;x<5;x++){
             if(file[x][2].equalsIgnoreCase(prog2))
                 System.out.println(file[x][0]+";"+file[x][1]);
           }
           System.out.print("Press [r] to return to main manu....");
           r=copy.next();
           if("r".equals(r))
           break;
       case 4:
           System.out.println("******[4]Output******");
           for(int x=0;x<5;x++){
             if(file[x][2].equalsIgnoreCase(cso))
               System.out.println(file[x][0]+";"+file[x][1]);
           }
           System.out.print("Press [r] to return to main manu....");
           r=copy.next();
           if("r".equals(r))
           break;
       case 5:
           menu=5;
   }
   }while(menu!=5);
```

Comment: You should tag your question with which programming language you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question, then you don't need a try/catch here. Just use a counter to keep track of how many things have been printed. If counter is 0, print the message:

```
case 3:
    System.out.println("******[3]Output*****");

    int counter = 0;

    for(int x=0;x<5;x++){
        if(file[x][2].equalsIgnoreCase(prog2)) {
            System.out.println(file[x][0]+";"+file[x][1]);
            counter += 1;
        }
    }

    if (0 == counter) {
        System.out.println("NO ENROLLED students...");
    }

    System.out.print("Press [r] to return to main manu....");
    r=copy.next();
    if("r".equals(r))
    break;
```

Comment: No problem. If this answer helped you please mark it as accepted (click the check box to the left of the answer).